# Separating a date array to have different output for 1st date in array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, date

Basically I am building a calendar/event booking system on my local PC for personal use, I have the functionality working to get the days from my database that have a booking attached to them, and you recolour the dates in the array accordingly, but I'm trying to work out if I could customise the result of the 1st day in each range, and the following days being the same.

Here is how it looks(if it makes it any easier)

[image: How it is now]

[image: Photoshop version of desired result]

And here is the code I am currently using on the page..

```
<?php 
function date_range($first, $last, $step = '+1 day', $output_format = 'Y-m-d' ) {

$dates = array();
$current = strtotime($first);
$last = strtotime($last);

while( $current <= $last ) {

    $dates[] = date($output_format, $current);
    $current = strtotime($step, $current);
}
return $dates;
}
?>
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="background-color: #aaaaaa;">
   <?php
  $cmonth = date('F'); 
  $cyear = date('Y');

$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM trips WHERE year(start_date) = '$cyear' ORDER BY start_date ASC");
$array_days = array();
while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {

$selected_dates = date_range(date("Y-m-d",strtotime($rows['start_date'])), date("Y-m-d",strtotime($rows['end_date'])));
foreach($selected_dates as $selected_date){
    $array_days[$selected_date]['start_end'] = "". $rows['trip_start'] . " to " . $rows['trip_end'];
    $array_days[$selected_date]['colour'] = "". $rows['colour'];
    $array_days[$selected_date]['booked'] = "". $rows['booked'];
    $array_days[$selected_date]['capacity'] = "". $rows['capacity'];
    }
}
?>
<tr>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
     <?php for($i=1;$i<=31;$i++){?>
        <td class="trip-date-cell"><?php echo $i;?></td>
     <?php }?>
</tr>
<?php 
$current_month = date("m");
$next_6_month = date("m", strtotime("+5 month", strtotime(date("F") . "1")));
for($i=$current_month;$i<=$next_6_month;$i++){  // 12 months in year
?>
 <tr>
 <td class="trip-month-cell"><?php echo date('M', mktime(0, 0, 0, $i,10, $cyear)); ?></td>
<?php 
$days_in_month = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN,$i,$cyear);

foreach (range(1, $days_in_month) as $days) {
    $key = date('Y-m-d', mktime(0, 0, 0, $i, $days, $cyear));
    if(array_key_exists($key,$array_days)){
    $color = $array_days[$key]['capacity'] - $array_days[$key]['booked'] == 0 ? "#303030" : $array_days[$key]['colour'];
    echo "<td class='trip-day-book' style='background-color: ".$color."' alt='".$array_days[$key]['start_end']."' title='".$array_days[$key]['start_end']."'>&nbsp;</td>";
    } else {
    echo "<td class='trip-day-blank'>&nbsp;</td>";
  }
}
?>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
 </table>
```

Any suggestions or advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store the first date information in your array when reading in the date ranges:

```
while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {

    $selected_dates = date_range(date("Y-m-d",strtotime($rows['start_date'])), date("Y-m-d",strtotime($rows['end_date'])));

    // default to true: first date is first day in range
    $firstDate = true;

    foreach($selected_dates as $selected_date) {

        // store first day info in array
        $array_days[$selected_date]['first_day'] = $firstDate;

        // set to false for all following days
        if ($firstDate) $firstDate = false;

        $array_days[$selected_date]['start_end'] = "". $rows['trip_start'] . " to " . $rows['trip_end'];
        $array_days[$selected_date]['colour'] = "". $rows['colour'];
        $array_days[$selected_date]['booked'] = "". $rows['booked'];
        $array_days[$selected_date]['capacity'] = "". $rows['capacity'];
    }
}
```

and then while rendering access the information to achieve your desired result:

```
$color = $array_days[$key]['capacity'] - $array_days[$key]['booked'] == 0 ? "#303030" : $array_days[$key]['colour'];
// set content of cell according to first day info
$content = $array_days[$key]['first_day'] ? '<strong>1</strong>' : '&nbsp;'; 
echo "<td class='trip-day-book' style='background-color: ".$color."' alt='".$array_days[$key]['start_end']."' title='".$array_days[$key]['start_end']."'>$content</td>";
```